# What vectors are orthogonal to $(3,2,-5)$ and have components that sum to 4?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have so far that $(3,2,-5) \cdot (x,y,z)= 3x + 2y -5z =0$ and $x+y+z=4$ must be true. Combining these equations gives us $4x+3y-4z=4$. If this is the right track, I'm not sure where do I take it from here?

Comment: Solve the system of equations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since number of variables $3$ is bigger than the number of equations $2$ then you will have one free variable, say $z=t$ and the infinite number of solutions is given by

$$ \left\{(-8+7t, 12-8t,t):\,\quad t\in \mathbb{R} \right\} $$

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations: $3x + 2y -5z = 0$ and $x+y+z=4$. To solve system of equation you need third equation, for example by choosing value of $z$, for example $z=0$. Now put $z=0$ to your two equations and solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: If I do that, wouldn't I fail to find ALL such orthogonal vectors? I would then only be solving for the vectors where $z=0$?

Comment: Yes, if you want to find all vectors you can for example solve equations for $x,y$ without putting $z=0$. You get something like $x=az+c$ and $y=bz+d$ and any $z \in \mathbb{R}$ for some constant $a,b,c,d$.